# Setting Page Title Yoast

Tags: title

So I'm having a little bit of trouble with the page title. I have created a plugin which fetches product data from an API. This happens in the content.

However, the title of the car (I'm fetching cars) has to be the page title.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
public function setTitle($title) {
    // Get meta data
    $meta = $this->meta();

    return $meta->title;
}
```

Then I'm registering it with `add_filter( 'the_title' )` and `add_filter( 'wpseo_thetitle' )`.

This is working for `the_title()` output but not for the page title.
My guess is because my plugin fetches the content later on, there isn't a title yet so he falls back to the original page title.

Is there a possibility to do this later on, so that I can set the page title after the content has been loaded?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to modify document's `<title>` tag as opposed to the post titles typically wrapped in `<h1>`/`<h2>` tags, which you've already accomplished.

If the theme you're using implements titles in the [WordPress 4.4+ manner](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/20/document-title-in-4-4/), you can use the `document_title_parts` filter:

```
/**
 * document_title_parts
 *
 * Filters the parts of the document title.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param array $title {
 *     The document title parts.
 *
 *     @type string $title   Title of the viewed page.
 *     @type string $page    Optional. Page number if paginated.
 *     @type string $tagline Optional. Site description when on home page.
 *     @type string $site    Optional. Site title when not on home page.
 * }
 */
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'wpse241607_document_title_parts', 10, 1 );

function wpse241607_document_title_parts( $title ) {

    $title['title'] = '##### ' . $title['title'] . ' #####';

    return $title;
}
```

For Yoast SEO, you can check out the [`wpseo_title`](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/) filter, which is used to filter the title text.

Comment: Hi Dave, Yes, i ment the document title. I did tried this approach but i have to fetch the title from the content but the title is already set then i guess as i can't seem to get it changed with my dynamic values(static work.

Comment: Seems like maybe you would need to fetch it early to get it into the document title then the content later. If it's an external API call, then perhaps it would make more sense to grab this data on the post edit screen and save it in metadata, then you'd have it anywhere it's needed without an external call. (In a previous comment I suggested grabbing the data in wpse241607_document_title_parts() and saving it in a global, but after sleeping on it decided that was not such a great approach).